# Terraform returns “i/o timeout” error when speaking to AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform

When I execute any action that requires Terraform to speak to AWS services, I receive this kind of error:

```
Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: IAM Role (arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/terraform-role) cannot be assumed.
│
│ There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
│   * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
│   * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
│   * The role ARN is not valid
│
│ Error: operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , request send failed, Post "https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: lookup sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on 1.1.1.1:53: read udp 192.168.1.246:0->1.1.1.1:53: i/o timeout
│
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 13, in provider "aws":
│   13: provider "aws" {
```

What I’ve tested so far:

1. Another Macbook connected to the same network and have the same
   software versions installed is working well.
2. Switching to another network does not help.
3. Tried with the Internet provider’s DNS server(192.168.1.1), with Google’s (8.8.8.8), with CloudFlare’s (1.1.1.1) - no difference.
4. The command `dig @1.1.1.1 sts.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` works just fine.
5. AWS CLI can talk to STS without any issues.
6. If I run a Terraform within a container, and mount my AWS credentials as a volume, it works just fine. So the problem is only when I run it via the local terminal.
7. Tried different versions of Terraform, namely 1.2.5, 1.0.0, and 1.0.3 - no difference.

I’m running out of ideas, any help please?

Versions:

```
macOS Monterey, version 12.5
Terraform v1.2.5
aws-cli/2.0.30 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/21.6.0 botocore/2.0.0dev34
Go runtime version: go1.18.1
```

Comment: `1.1.1.1` is not the address of STS. What exactly are you doing that you have `1.1.1.1`?

Comment: @Marcin It's a DNS server. OP is getting a timeout on DNS resolution. Error says UDP port 53.

Comment: Are you running anything that modifies dns settings like telepresence?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, 1.1.1.1 is CloudFlare's DNS server, but I get the same with Google's and others. Re: telepresence and other things - I thought about something blocking my DNS requests, but the error I see only goes from Terraform. I can execute any "aws sts" commands from my terminal without any issues.